# Recursive discriminated unions and map

Tags: recursion, f#, functor, discriminated-union

I need a type of tree and a map on those, so I do this:

```
type 'a grouping = 
    G of ('a * 'a grouping) list
    with 
        member g.map f = 
            let (G gs) = g
            gs |> List.map (fun (s, g) -> f s, g.map f) |> G
```

But this makes me wonder:

1. The `map` member is boilerplate. In Haskell, GHC would implement `fmap` for me (`... deriving (Functor)`). I know F# doesn't have typeclasses, but is there some other way I can avoid writing map myself in F#?
2. Can I somehow avoid the line `let (G gs) = g`?
3. Is this whole construction somehow non-idiomatic? It looks weird to me, but maybe that's just because putting members on sum types is new to me.

Comment: Did you consider a let-bound function `let rec map f (G gs) = gs |> List.map (fun (s, g) -> f s, map f g) |> G`?

Comment: Yeah. I wanted to avoid it, though: The neat thing about using `member` seemed to be that I avoid polluting my local namespace with things named `mapG` and `foldG` and such. And I don't get to let-bind a member, right?

Comment: @SørenDebois: This is as good as it gets. If you try to emulate Haskell in F# your code will end up a lot more convoluted than your current (straightforward) solution.

Comment: @SørenDebois - It might be slightly more idiomatic to make it a let-bound definition within a `Grouping` module; then you can just open the module if you're going to be using it a lot and use `map` in an unqualified way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to derive automatically `map`, however there's a way to [emulate type classes in F#](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl), your code can be written like this:

```
#r @"FsControl.Core.dll"
#r @"FSharpPlus.dll"

open FSharpPlus
open FsControl.Core.TypeMethods

type 'a grouping = 
    G of ('a * 'a grouping) list
    with
        // Add an instance for Functor 
        static member instance (_:Functor.Map, G gs, _) = fun (f:'b->'c) -> 
            map (fun (s, g) -> f s, map f g) gs |> G

// TEST
let a = G [(1, G [2, G[]] )]
let b = map ((+) 10) a        // G [(11, G [12, G[]] )]
```

Note that `map` is really overloaded, the first application you see calls the instance for `List<'a>` and the second one the instance for `grouping<'a>`. So it behaves like `fmap` in Haskell.

Also note this way you can decompose `G gs` without creating the `let (G gs) = g`

Now regarding what is idiomatic I think many people would agree your solution is more F# idiomatic, but to me new idioms should also be developed in order to get more features and overcome current language limitations, that's why I consider using a library which define clear conventions also idiomatic.

Anyway I agree with @kvb in that it's slightly more idiomatic to define `map` into a module, in [F#+](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus) that convention is also used, so you have the generic `map` and the specific `ModuleX.map`

Comment: Intriguing. Could you explain or point someplace where I can go read about what's going on with the `instance (_:Functor.Map, G gs, _)`?

Comment: Have a look at the readme file at https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/master/README.md I will be interested in your feedback so please tell me if you think I can add something else to the explanation.